# Keyboard shortcut to switch to a specific Chrome window

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome

Ok, I realize this is asking for the impossible. I habitually have about 4 Chrome windows open. On linux, I have a system set up so I have a different keyboard shortcut to switch to each window, so I can jump to the correct one really quickly.

Is there possibly a way to do this on OSX? I'm willing to write moderate amounts of code if necessary to implement this, 'though I should probably head over to StackOverflow if that looks like it will be needed.

Comment: How would you identify the windows or decide which one to focus? Do you keep them on different spaces or something?

Comment: No, not difference spaces. Some other attribute of the window might be possible, though, like the order in which they were created. That's the way it works on linux.

Comment: How about creating a macro which would select the Window menu and then click at (X,Y) for the window you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try
    set text item delimiters to linefeed
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        reopen
        do shell script "sort -n <<< " & quoted form of (id of windows as text) & " | sed -n 3p"
        set w to window id (result as integer)
        set b to bounds of w
        set t to title of w
    end tell
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "Google Chrome"
        window 1 where position is {item 1 of b, item 2 of b} and title is t
        perform action "AXRaise" of result
        set frontmost to true
    end tell
end try
```

Windows that were created later usually have a larger id. If the script is run when there's no second window, there won't be an error dialog because it's wrapped in a try block.

You can give the scripts shortcuts [with FastScripts or by creating Automator services](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/).

Comment: Thanks a ton! This is exactly what I wanted. I ended up calling out to a custom python script instead of using UNIX utilities, but this is pretty much what I'm now doing.